# Deploy a project to SSISDB using T-SQL Script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

My project has 3 servers Dev for devlopment, Test for Testing and prod for production. I am asked to create SSISDB catalogs from scratch in all the 3 servers.

The folder is named ABC_Dev. Now I have to deploy the SSIS Project into folder named ABC_Devfolder using T-SQL Script. When the script runs on all 3 environments, the project and all the SSIS packages should be deployed into the catalog folder.

I tried something like this

```
    DECLARE @ProjectBinary as varbinary(max)
    DECLARE @operation_id as bigint
   Set @ProjectBinary = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '<projectpath.ispac>', SINGLE_BLOB) as 
   BinaryData)

  Exec catalog.deploy_project @folder_name = 'ABC_Dev', @project_name = 'ABC_Dev', 
  @Project_Stream = @ProjectBinary, @operation_id = @operation_id out
 
 '<projectpath.ispac>' - I gave the path as 
  C:\Users\ABC_Dev\SSIS\ABC_Dev\bin\Development\ABC_Dev.ispac
```

Somehow its not taking that path on the servers.

Is there a way to declare the .ispac path that runs on all 3 servers when T-SQL script executes

Comment: Don't forget, a path will be relative to the server not to you. Your path looks like a path for something stored locally, not on the hosts. I also, personally, doubt that the SQL Server Service Account will have access to another user's User Directory; it shouldn't.